# Compute next hop routing table from adjacency matrix using Dijkstra's algorithm - alg. not stopping

Tags: c++, algorithm, graph, routes, dijkstra

I am trying to determine a next hop routing table using an [adjacency matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adjacency_matrix). Each node knows the full adjacency matrix for that topology. I have found previous  posts explaining how to do it, however, I don't understand why mine is wrong. I have a couple of helper functions but their names are intuitive so you could skip to " starting routing calculations".

I use the adjacency matrix as a cost matrix, it just has only 0's and 1's. The algorithm seems not to stop for some reason.  The queue gets stuck on size 1,3 or 5 depending on node.

The variable rank holds the current node index, it is run in OpenMPI so each process(rank / node) runs this chunk of code independently. Variable matrix holds the adjacency matrix.
Here is the topology I am using :

```
               0
             /    \
           1       2
       / /  | \   /  \
      3  4  5  6 7    8
        / \           |
       9  10          11
```

Adjacency matrix : 
(As seen by Node 3, one of those that does not stop );

```
1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
1 0 0 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 
1 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 
0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 0 
0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 
0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0
```

My code so far:

```
int isFull(int *d, int size) {
    int i;

    for(i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        if(d[i] == INF) {
            return -1;
        }
    }
    return 1;
}
int vecSize(int *d, int size) {
    int counter = 0;
    int i;
    for(i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        if(d[i] != INF) {
            counter++;
        }
    }
    return counter;
}
bool List_contains(std::list<int > l, int val) {
    for (std::list<int>::const_iterator iterator = l.begin(), end = l.end(); iterator != end; ++iterator) {
        if (*iterator == val) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
int minimum (int a, int b) {
    if (a < b) {
        return a;
    }
    return b;
}
/* matrix is the complete adjacency matrix */


/* starting routing calculations
 *
 */
std::list <int > visited;
int *dist;
dist = (int*) calloc(size, sizeof(int));
visited.push_back(rank);

//debug
//printf("debug not empty %d\n", isFull(dist, size));
for(i = 0; i < size; i++) {
    if(matrix[rank][i] == 1) {
        dist[i] = 1;
    } else {
        dist[i] = INF;
    }
}
dist[rank] = 0;
int min;
while(isFull(dist,size) < 0) {
    if(rank == 3)
        printf("node - %d -debug -- list size %d\n",rank, vecSize(dist, size));
    //get the first node that isn't contained
    for(i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        if (!List_contains(visited, i) && min != rank) {
            min = i;
            break;
        }
    }

    for(i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        if((min >= dist[i]) && (!List_contains(visited, i)) && min != rank) {
            min = i;
        }
    }
    if(rank == 3)
        printf("min = %d\n", min);
    visited.push_back(min);

    for(i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        if((matrix[min][i] == 1) && (!List_contains(visited, i))) {
            dist[i] = minimum (dist[i], dist[min] + matrix[min][i]);
        }
    }
    if(rank == 3)
        //printf("rank %d dist = \n", rank);
    for(i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        if(rank == 3)
            printf("%d ", dist[i]);
    }
    if(rank == 3)
        printf("\n");
}
/*
 * finished routing calculations.
 */
```

This would be the output so far : http://pastebin.com/x5wjKkyn

Could someone point out what am I doing wrong? Thank you !
Later edit: Technically, the algorithm provides the correct distances, it just doesn't stop. ( The output is exclusively from node 0)

Later edit: it seems that the program is not stopping because for some nodes the algo doesn't finish.

Comment: Your code as it is posted isn't compilable. For example, how is `INF` defined? Remember: http://sscce.org/

Comment: Sorry, INF is defined as 999. #define INF 999

Comment: I always thought _inf_ was much much higher than that...

Comment: I defined it as it was needed, the topology is at most 20(However, I do not see how this is relevant to my issue). As a result without routing loops there is no way it should get to 999 hops.

Comment: @pAndrei You don't provide the actual adjacency matrix either. While it's trivial to figure out, writing it out takes time and makes it less likely someone will answer. Being able to copy-paste the code, copile it, and fire up a debugger is invaluable.

Comment: @Yuushi, you are indeed right. Thank you for that site(sscce.org)! The main I didn't post my adjacency matrix  is that I do not read it, it is generated by exchanging messages between nodes and adding that code aswell was redundant. I added the matrix too, now.

Comment: What have you done to debug your code on your own?

Comment: @Code-Guru, I don't know how to use a debugger on openMPI, not sure if it exists. I added several printf's in the code( still doing on points I am checking) and adding sleep()'s to slow down the algorithm so I can track each step. I have been debuggging since I posted it.

Comment: I updated the pastebin so that the issue is visible, basically the alg. keeps adding on elements in the list even tho it shouldn't and for some reason when it adds an element to list it does not change the dist vector, I will investigate

Comment: @pAndrei `printf()`s are a great debugging tool!

Comment: what about rewrite it to non-parallel code debug it and after success  port to parallel .. so you can use debugger normally. Also parallel algorithm can be run in debugger (try threads instead of MPI for debug purposes). This way will be clear if the bug is in algorithm or process synchronization